# How to Create Dropdown columns in Sales > Order Grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales, drop-downs

I want to create drop-down column in sales > order grid.So How to Create this column.

```
<?php

namespace Test\OrderColumns\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;


class SalesRep  extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;

    protected $_searchCriteria;
 
    /**
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
 
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $order->getData("sales_rep");
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Test\OrderColumns\Model;

use Test\OrderColumns\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $loadedData;

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $Test,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $Test->create();
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $Test) {
            $this->loadedData[$Test->getId()] = $Test->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

---

```
 <column name="cs_rep">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Test\OrderColumns\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CsRep</item>
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <!-- <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">999</item> -->
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">CS Rep</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                   <!-- <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item> -->
                   <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
```

---

This is model file

```
<?php

namespace Test\OrderColumns\Model\Source;

class CsRep implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            [
                'value' => '0',
                'label' => __('Do not need a tracking info')
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'custom',
                'label' => __('Custom')
            ]
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Model file call in this file

```
<?php

namespace Test\OrderColumns\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;


class CsRep extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;

    protected $_searchCriteria;
 
    /**
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        \Test\OrderColumns\Model\Source\CsRep $csRep,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->csRep = $csRep;
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
 
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $this->csRep->toOptionArray();
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Please Help me,

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: what is the data source?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson i have update my code for Ui and DataProvider

Comment: first Ui is text but i want to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` in your custom module.

The class specified in the `<options>` must implement `\Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="my_column_name" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Class\Of\Option\Values\Source"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">My Column</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Here is a real life example from Magento core code

```
<column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
    <settings>
        <filter>select</filter>
        <options class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
        <dataType>select</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Status</label>
    </settings>
</column>
```

Comment: can you possible share "Class\Of\Option\Values\Source" code. So i will check dear

Comment: An example that you could copy and modify is a native Magento class like `\Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Optons`

Comment: It is not working showing blank not show dropdown https://prnt.sc/xhk71w

Comment: Be sure to flush your caches. If its still not working, please post your sales_order_grid.xml file and the content of your options class

Comment: It is not working i have update my question. pls check

Comment: This is because your xml doesn't follow my example. Additionally, your filter type is date not select

Comment: again i have checked but not working

Comment: pls check https://prnt.sc/xi5hmv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118849/discussion-between-mohit-patel-and-shawn-abramson).

Comment: Definitely the options node is not in the correct place in the XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create File sales_order_grid.xml in your module's view/adminhtml/ui_component folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
       <column name="your_column_name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Items</item>
            <item name="component". xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Create file Options.php in your module's Ui\Component\Listing\Column folder

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Options implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
   
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Do not need a tracking info')],
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Custom')]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to save value?

Comment: I think ,In the editor you have the the save url path like this:
 <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="Vendor_Module/inlineEdit"/>

In this controller file you can add your code for save this attribute